# [Solved] How to convert urdf to sdf (gz not working)

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a little bit of context, I'm using ros Foxy with Ubuntu 20.04
My initial goal was to use the gazebo_ros_p3d plugin in gazebo by adding :

```
<gazebo>
<plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so" name="gazebo_ros_p3d">
  <bodyName>bannane</bodyName>
  <topicName>ground_truth_odom</topicName>
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
</plugin>
```

into my .urdf description of the robot.
Everything seem to work fine, the robot spawn in gazebo however i get this error :

```
[gazebo-4] [ERROR] [1651828364.494524675] [gazebo_ros_p3d]: Missing <body_name>, cannot proceed
```

This led me to look here : http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__p3d_8cpp_source.html.
Apparently my .sdf file does not contains a body_name which is weird as it seems present in my urdf file.

I then tried to look at what the sdf file looked like, and found an issue :

```
$ gz sdf -p bot_description.urdf > test
Error: SDF parsing the xml failed
```

I believe the issue comes from here, gazebo don't need .sdf file to work so the simulation work fine but as the conversion fail i can't get the plugin to work.
Is there a way to get more information on why does the conversion is failing ?
How can i add my .urdf to this post if needed ?
Thank you everyone for taking time to read my question !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400252/%5Bsolved%5D-how-to-convert-urdf-to-sdf-(gz-not-working)/) by [Bastian2909](https://answers.ros.org/users/102337/bastian2909/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2022-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-09**:
Please post your last edit as an answers instead, then accept your own answer.

**Comment by [Bastian2909](https://answers.ros.org/users/102337/bastian2909/) on 2022-05-09**:
done, thank you for the advice, will do that from now on.
however I can't accept my own answer as I don't have enough points.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-09**:
I've already accepted it for you.

**Comment by [Bastian2909](https://answers.ros.org/users/102337/bastian2909/) on 2022-05-09**:
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the issue !
I followed a tutorial telling me to create a .urdf file and calling it a urdf file even though there was some xacro prensent in the code. This led me to beleive my file was a .urdf file but it was a .xacro file.
So i first converted my .urdf file to a true .urdf file using the xacro -> urdf converter.
Then i was able to convert my true .urdf file into an sdf without any issue.

---

Originally posted by [Bastian2909](https://answers.ros.org/users/102337/bastian2909/) with karma: 68 on 2022-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0